# Change list state with checkbuttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to present a list of files in a directory that will be processed by my program. I use Tkinter with python.

The only way I have hit idea on is to make a list of files that each file is represented by list where first value is file name, second is 1 if proccess 0 if no.

```
os.chdir("/home/user/files")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    listOfFiles.append([file, 0])

for f in listOfFiles:
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=f[0], variable=f[1])
    c.pack()
```

Actually this part of code does not work because it does not change a second item for each file. Is there any good solution for my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a command callback in the Checkbutton statement, or use a Button to process them. The simplest way would be to append each checked file to a separate list, and process that list.  So for the sample code below, instead of printing "something is checked", append the file name (text from the checkbox in program) to another list.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk     # Python2
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk     # Python3

def cb_checked():
    # show checked check button item(s)
    label['text'] = ''
    for ix, item in enumerate(cb):
        if cb_v[ix].get():     ## IntVar not zero==checked
            label['text'] += '%s is checked' % item['text'] + '\n'

root = tk.Tk()

cb_list = [
'apple',
'orange',
'banana',
'pear',
'apricot'
]

# list(range()) needed for Python3
# list of each button object
cb = list(range(len(cb_list)))
# list of IntVar for each button
cb_v = list(range(len(cb_list)))
for ix, text in enumerate(cb_list):
    # IntVar() tracks checkbox status (1=checked, 0=unchecked)
    cb_v[ix] = tk.IntVar()
    # command is optional and responds to any cb changes
    cb[ix] = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=text,
                            variable=cb_v[ix], command=cb_checked)
    cb[ix].grid(row=ix, column=0, sticky='w')

label = tk.Label(root, width=20)
label.grid(row=ix+1, column=0, sticky='w')

# you can preset check buttons (1=checked, 0=unchecked)
cb_v[3].set(1)
# show initial selection
cb_checked()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So is is easy also to use buttons for this purpose?